# Re-create folder after re-start of window service using Topshelf

Tags: c#, topshelf

I am using `Topshelf` for window service and I used configuration `AfterInstall` to create a folder `CreateFolder`.

Now when I install/start service, the folder gets created. Nice!

lets say after some time I stopped my service and delete the folder which creates, then upon re-start of service, I want to folder to be re-created. Is this possible?

Is there any setting within `Topshelf` configuration so that on re-start of service folder will create again?

```
HostFactory.Run(
        configuration =>
        {
            configuration.AfterInstall(CreateFolder);
            configuration.Service<Service1>(
                service =>
                {
                    service.ConstructUsing(x => new Service1());
                    service.WhenStarted(x => x.Start());
                    service.WhenStopped(x => x.Stop());
                });
            configuration.EnableServiceRecovery(recoveryOption =>
            {
                recoveryOption.RestartService(1);
            });

            configuration.RunAsVirtualServiceAccount();

            configuration.SetServiceName("TEST");

            configuration.StartAutomatically();
```

"CreateFolder" Method below here,

```
static void CreateFolder()
    {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(some path);
    }
```

Comment: According their [specs](http://docs.topshelf-project.com/en/latest/configuration/config_api.html#custom-service), they have only `AfterInstall` and `After/BeforeUninstall` custom actions

Comment: AFAIK There's no `OnRestart` in TopShelf, but you can simply do `Directory.CreateDirectory(some path);` on the service `Start()` method - if the directory already exists when restarting the service nothing will happen, but if it doesn't exist it will be created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TopShelf only has custom actions for the AfterInstall. You could tie into the service Start() function to check for and create the directory using the Directory.CreateDirectory(path) method.